# Cmd line installation of SQL Server fails with : The setting 'browsersvcstartuptype' specified is not recognized message

Tags: sql-server, cmd

I am trying to install SQL server 2016 Express version using the command line tool. It fails with the message : The setting 'browsersvcstartuptype' specified is not recognized and The setting 'sqlsvcstartuptype' specified is not recognized.

I went through the documentation on msdn and also copied the sample install statement replacing with my .exe. Below is the command I am trying to run

```
SQLServer2016-SSEI-Expr.exe /q /ACTION=Install /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic 
/FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS2016 /SQLSVCACCOUNT=\"NT AUTHORITY\\Network Service\" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=\"BUILTIN\\ADMINISTRATORS\ 
/AGTSVCACCOUNT=\"NT AUTHORITY\\Network Service\" /SAPWD=CoolSign@123 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

We should be seeing the install process begin, but doesnt go through and the above mentioned error messages are being flashed.

Can anyone tell me what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Well, those options were added in SQL Server 2017, so 2016  has no idea what they are. Compare [2016 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-2016) and [2017 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-2017) and consider using 2017 in favor 2016 because, well, it's newer, better, and will be in support that much longer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I get the same error when I use the SQLServer2017-SSEI-Expr.exe in place of the 2016 exe.

Comment: SQLServer2017-SSEI-Expr.exe is just a wrapper for the installer, you can't install SQL Server directly by calling the wrapper from the command line, and those articles don't apply to SSEI-Expr.exe. You need to run that exe manually, choose the `Download Media` option, pick a folder, then run `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe` with the command line options above.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually you will need to run `setup.exe` after extracting `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe`. You can use SSEI-Expr.exe at the command line to automate downloading, using for example `/ACTION=Download /MEDIAPATH=C:\temp\whatever` - but while there is an `/ACTION=Install` option, you don't have all the flexibility there that you have with the proper (non-wrapper) installer. You can see the options available by running `SQLServer2017-SSEI-Expr.exe /?`, `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe /?`, and finally `setup.exe /?` - the latter has dozens more options than the others.

Comment: Use a '/q' flag with SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe to silently extract the directory containing setup.exe